# What do you call open gaps inbetween teeth, systemic throughout the mouth?

Tags: word-choice

You would think this would be something a dentist knows.  I've asked scores of dentists this very question and no one has an answer.  It's got to have a name.

It's fairly common.  The teeth don't touch the ones adjacent.  There's a tooth and then an open half space and then another tooth and so on.  The whole mouth is like this.  LOL  I'm sure there MUST be a name for this.  I've been trying to find the name for this for more than 20 years.

I acknowledge that this is, surely, a genetic condition but I left "genetic condition" out of my title.  It may or may not be an esoteric medical term.  I just want to know what it's called.  Further, I'm not talking about people with gaps, Elton John style, between their two front teeth.  I'm talking about gaps between every tooth in their head.

Comment: They're all diastemas, Elton John has a Mid-Line Diastema. *A diastema that occurs because of a [genetic] mismatch between the teeth and the jaw does not have symptoms.* -[Colgate](http://www.colgate.com/app/CP/US/EN/OC/Information/Articles/Cosmetic-Dentistry/Orthodontics/Orthodontic-Basics/article/Diastema-Gap-Between-Teeth.cvsp) ; it is not a genetic disorder. *They* are in disorder because of their genetics.

Comment: How about "gap-toothed" - as in "A gap-toothed smile". Or, lacking an official term, you could use something descriptive like: "A smile like an open zipper."

Comment: @Mazura The more I think about it, the more I think you're on to something.  The people who have these gaps between their teeth have unusually small teeth (like baby teeth, only these are in the mouth of very mature adults, 35+).  LOL  It could be I'm noticing the wrong thing.  I'm noticing that there's a half-space in between every tooth but that is exactly what extremely small teeth would get you.  Perhaps, what it is, is all under the heading of extremely small teeth, whatever that is.

Answer (score 2):

The phenomenon of a gap between adjacent teeth is known as a [diastema](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diastema) (plural *diastemata*).

Comment: You're doing a good job of describing gap(s) between teeth. Although close, that's not what I'm asking.  I'm asking what you call a person who has a gap between every tooth.  For example, if you described such a person as having "diastematic teeth", that really wouldn't describe it very well.  That could mean gaps between two teeth or all of them.  I'm looking for a word that describes gaps between every last tooth.

Comment: @AllisonHunt - I suspect that no such term exists, in which case *diastema* will be as good an answer as you'll get. I suggest you try asking on the [biology Stackexchange site](http://biology.stackexchange.com/) to cover all the bases.

Comment: @AllisonHunt - you didn't ask that in your question or your title. A bit late to ask for it now.

Comment: Plural: diastemata

Comment: According to my dictionary *diastema* specifically refers to a gap between different types of teeth e.g. between incisors and molars. Though it can refer to one between the two front teeth. My impression is that it is not a widely used term by dentists, but I may be wrong. Do they not talk of *spacing*?

Answer (score 1):

The term is [*diastema*](http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/diastema) or more commonly [*interdental space.*](http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/interdental+space)

Source: medical-dictionary.theFree Dictionary.com